# nyromodal v2 autoresizing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, nyromodal

I am currently migrating to a new version of the wonderful jquery nyromodal-plugin.

In any version prior to 2.0 the plugin had a configuration switch which enabled the window to resize when the content changed dynamically. 
It was enabled like this.

```
$.nyroModalSettings({
  autoSizable: true,
  ..
});
```

As the version 2 is a complete rewrite the whole api changed. I double-checked the documentation and read the source-code. Unfortunately I didn't find a similar configuration option.

I found the resize method which is capable of changing the size according to the content, but I am really not sure how and when to call it. The offered callback hooks just don't seam suitable.

Did anybody run into the same problem?

Comment: what about the `resize` function? The documentation says "@param recalc boolean: Indicate if the size should be recalaculated (useful when content has changed)". Maybe that can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't any feture to autoresize the content.
You had to call a function in version 1.

In version 2, you have to call a function too.
After updating you're content, you have to call:

```
$.nmTop().resize(true);
```